# javascript, get array of numbers from random string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I keep getting undefined function error at nums.match(). I have tried other methods as well, to no success.

I want to create a general function in javascript that will extract all numbers from a random string and add them into an array, in the order of extraction. Any Idea why I keep getting this error?

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Here is my current function:

```
var nums="A rectangle measuring 30.0 cm by 40.0 cm is located inside a region of a spatially uniform magnetic field of 1.35T , with the field perpendicular to the plane of the coil. The coil is pulled out at a steady rate of 2.00 cm/s traveling perpendicular to the field lines. The region of the field ends abruptly as shown.";
 nums = nums.match(/\d+\.?\d*/g);

alert(nums);
var bookNums = nums.split(" ");
alert(bookNums[0],bookNums[1],bookNums[2]);
```

Comment: `nums` is not a string. It doesn't have a method `.split`. `nums` is an array or `null`. You can read about what `.match` does and what it returns in the [**MDN documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

Comment: How would I do this then? So match is returning an array of strings containing the numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the assignment in your second line of code, `nums` is an array not a string. There is no `Array.prototype.split`, which is causing your error. Because [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an array, `nums` already contains the values you want (or `null` if no matches were found).

Here's a rewrite that should work:

```
var nums = "A rectangle measuring 30.0 cm by 40.0 cm is located inside a region of a spatially uniform magnetic field of 1.35T , with the field perpendicular to the plane of the coil. The coil is pulled out at a steady rate of 2.00 cm/s traveling perpendicular to the field lines. The region of the field ends abruptly as shown.";
var bookNums = nums.match(/\d+\.?\d*/g);

console.log(bookNums);    // array or null
```

Comment: Wow, always the silly stuff Im getting caught up on. Thank you!

Comment: javascript's like that. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var nums="A rectangle measuring 30.0 cm by 40.0 cm is located inside a region of a spatially uniform magnetic field of 1.35T , with the field perpendicular to the plane of the coil. The coil is pulled out at a steady rate of 2.00 cm/s traveling perpendicular to the field lines. The region of the field ends abruptly as shown.";
var nums_array = nums.match(/\d+\.?\d*/g);
var bookNums = nums_array;
```